# #Android How to utf-8 encode to HttpPost?

Tags: android, encoding, utf-8

When you want to use utf-8 encode to make HTTP Request to Server for POST method?

```
public **** makeHttpRequest(String url, String method, List<NameValuePair> params) {
   try{

       DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
       HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
       httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

       HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
       HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
       inputStream = httpEntity.getContent();

   } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
   } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
   } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

**[Solve]-Just add utf-8 in your URLEncodeFormEnitity method**

```
  DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
  HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
  httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, "utf-8"));

  HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
  HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
  inputStream = httpEntity.getContent();
```

Comment: Great!!! At same time when pressing **Post Your Question** . you found the answer of question.

Comment: Thanks, just to record it and share to somebody who is thinking  encode question.